# Runtime Error 3134 - Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to fix it about hour but it's not work  Please help me :(

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO match_day( home_team, away_team, date, time, home_score, away_score, stadium) " & _
                  " VALUES('" & Me.textHT & "','" & Me.textAT & "',#" & Me.textDATE & "#,#" & Me.textTime & "#," & Me.textHS & "," & Me.textAS & ",'" & Me.textSTD & ",')"
```

Answer (score 5):

Are the fields for date and time considered reserved words and should be wrapped in brackets or ticks to qualify it as the column name...

```
..., [date], [time], ...
```

But I think it is most likely the trailing final comma before your final closing ) of the inserted values making it look like it wants another field to be inserted.

```
Me.textSTD & ",')"
```

change to

```
Me.textSTD & "')"
```

Comment: Not to mention it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar error - thanks to this post I realised that I had used a reserved name "note" in a table ( instead of "notes").

```
   StrSQL = "INSERT INTO option_notes ( OPTION_ID , USER_ID , [NOTE] )  VALUES ( " & currID & " , " & currUserID & " , '" & currNote & "' ) ; "
   CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL
```

I ended up changing the field name - however, wrapping the field name with [  ] allowed the code to execute correctly.